# XML Sitemap Error on Wordpress - "error on line 10 at column 61: Opening and ending tag mismatch: html line 0 and loc"

Tags: wordpress, xml-sitemap

I've recently launched a new website and am trying to view my XML sitemap so I can submit it to Google Search Console etc.

I did install the RankMath SEO plugin (which I've used before with no issues) and now I get this error when I try to view the sitemap:

**This page contains the following errors:**
*error on line 10 at column 61: Opening and ending tag mismatch: html line 0 and loc*

I thought it might be because of the plugin so removed, cleared cache and tried to use the YoastSEO plugin but that had the same result.

I get the error whenever I try to view using these URLs:

- domain.com/sitemap.xml
- domain.com/sitemap-index.xml
- domain.com/sitemap_index.xml

Any idea how I can fix the error and get my sitemap working?

In the source there is like 11k URLs which is wrong - I only have about 15 pages on the site. All the pages seem to be getting duplicated too.

[Here is the sitemap source code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbl9R.png)